# Assembly: what system return?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a code assembly and I think this code return olly value in address `[ebp+0x8]`
is `0xa254`. But answer it wrong. What did I miss?

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.bits 32

.global asm2

asm2:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp
    sub     esp,0x10
    mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
    mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],eax
    jmp     part_b
part_a: 
    add     DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x1
    add     DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x76
part_b: 
    cmp     DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0xa1de
    jle     part_a
    mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
    mov     esp,ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step by step

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.bits 32

.global asm2

asm2:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp
    sub     esp,0x10
    mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
    mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
    mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],eax
    jmp     part_b
part_a: 
    add     DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x1
    add     DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x76
part_b: 
    cmp     DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0xa1de
    jle     part_a
    mov     eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
    mov     esp,ebp
    pop     ebp
ret
```

let's first rename the call params to 'a', 'b' and the locals to 'x' and 'y'

```
asm2:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp
    sub     esp,0x10
    mov     eax,a
    mov     x,eax
    mov     eax,b
    mov     y,eax
    jmp     part_b
part_a: 
    add     x,0x1
    add     b,0x76
```

and now see what's going on

```
asm2:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp,esp       ; stack frame
    sub     esp,0x10      ; make some room for locals

    mov     eax,a
    mov     x,eax         ; x = a
    mov     eax,b
    mov     y,eax         ; y = b
    jmp     part_b        ; while (b <= 0xa1de)  { // condition see below
part_a: 
    add     x,0x1         ; x++;
    add     b,0x76        ; b+=76;
part_b: 
    cmp     b,0xa1de      ; } // condition for while: (b <= 0xa1de)
    jle     part_a
    mov     eax,x         ; return x;

    mov     esp,ebp       ; remove stackframe
    pop     ebp
ret
```

so you need to know what the parameters were to know what's returned. for what I see it's something like `a+(0xa1de-b)/0x76`